# CKEditor 4 font plugin error "CKEDITOR.tools.array.find is not a function" - missing dependencies?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEditor v.4.11.3 and have added the font plugin https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/font by downloading the zip and putting it in my plugins folder, and adding 'font' to config.extraPlugins in config.js. Font selector now shows up in my editor. Problem is when clicking on text in the editor or selecting a different font, browser dev tools shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.tools.array.find is not a function
    at b.findMatchingStyleName (plugin.js?t=J1QB:78)
    at Object.findMatchingStyleName (ckeditor.js:31)
    at b.getMatchingValue (plugin.js?t=J1QB:65)
    at $.<anonymous> (plugin.js?t=J1QB:221)
    at a.p (ckeditor.js:10)
    at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:12)
    at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13)
    at a.g (ckeditor.js:439)
    at a.CKEDITOR.editor.selectionChange (ckeditor.js:457)
    at $.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:453)
```

I also note that my editor version doesn't match any of those shown in the Releases table at the bottom of the Font plugin page https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/font

What's the easiest way to solve this situation without making matters worse?

I note there could be dependency issues here with the font plugin needing stuff I haven't added but not sure how to find out what that might be?

Or do I need to upgrade the editor? Willing to do that but don't want to make things worse or cause other problems!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To bypass this error, just **"return null"** at the **findMatchingStyleName** function

```
findMatchingStyleName: function( editor, element ) {
    return null
    /*
    return CKEDITOR.tools.array.find( this._.names, function( name ) {
        return this.getStyle( name ).checkElementMatch( element, true, editor );
                    }, this );
    */
}
```